# "Skip empty cells" behaviour not as expected

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I can't make heads nor tails of the "Skip empty cells" functionality in LibreOffice. When I copy the results of column A, and do Paste Special to column B, selecting "Skip empty cells", this is what I expect:

```
Before      After
A     B     A     B
-------     -------
£     $     £     £
      $           $
      $           $
```

This is what actually happens:

```
Before      After
A     B     A     B
-------     -------
£     $     £     $
      $           $
      $           $
```

Here's the Paste Special options I'm using.

[image]

Have I misunderstood what this is supposed to do? The Libreoffice documentation has scant advice to offer:

> Empty cells from the clipboard do not replace target cells. If you use this option in conjunction with the Multiply or the Divide operation, the operation is not applied to the target cell of an empty cell in the clipboard.

So I took this to mean that it will only paste non-null values into the column. It's not pasting *anything*. Is this a glitch with LibreOffice, or have I misunderstood the behaviour of this functionality?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on LO Calc 4.2.6.3. Could you please add a screenshot the `Paste special` options you're using?

Comment: Done. I'm using LO 4.2.2.1; I'll try to update.

Comment: Okay, there are no problems in the latest version, behaviour works as expected.

Comment: Great - and good idea to add the info as answer, so the issue is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a glitch confined to LO 4.2.2.1 - not confirmed as I have no repro. However, when I updated to version 4.3.1.2, the glitch disappeared, and the functionality works as expected.